# Use schema in shell

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

In a plugin context, I'm writing a shell subcommand and I need to call a public method of the schema:

```php
// app\Plugin\FooManager\Config\Schema\schema.php
App::uses('BaseSchema', 'FooManager.Config/Schema');
class FooManagerSchema extends BaseSchema {
    public function getLocalisableValues() {
    }
}
```

As usual, I can't figure out the syntax.

```php
// app\Plugin\FooManager\Console\Command\DevShell.php
class DevShell extends AppShell {
    public function i18n_dump_database_values() {
        $schema = ????????;
        $schema->getLocalisableValues();
    }
}
```

How can I load an instance of `FooManagerSchema` into `$schema`?

Comment: @DownVoter Not everybody is as smart as you. Please consider explaining how to improve this question to make it useful and clear or closing it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shameful cakeless workaround to make it work at any cost (please don't try this at home, kittens can be hurt):

```
// app\Plugin\FooManager\Console\Command\DevShell.php
class DevShell extends AppShell {
    public function i18n_dump_database_values() {
        // Ugly (and will possibly break things):
        include_once(__DIR__ . '/../../../../../lib/Cake/Model/CakeSchema.php');
        include_once(__DIR__ . '/../../Config/Schema/schema.php');
        $schema = new FooManagerSchema();

        $schema->getLocalisableValues();
    }
}
```